# Removing secuirty enforced email settings

Tags: windows, windows-10, email, exchange, email-client

When I joined my company I setup my company email which uses microsoft exchange on my home computer so I could read them at home as well as work It was setup on the Windows Mail client in Windows 10 and everything was great however recently they have started to enforce security policies. Every so often I get the dialog that says it wants to enforce security policy on my PC I click dismiss. Instead of enforcing the policy I wish to just delete the email account altogether. I thought it would be a simple thing to just delete the account in the Mail client however when when I go and click delete account it tells me it needs to enforce the policies so that it can delete it. Its like a chicken and egg scenario. Is there anyway I can defualt Windows 10 Mail client back to normal or phsyically remove the profile/settings somewhere.

Comment: Did you try to delete the mail profile from the control panel? 
Go to Control Panel -> User Accounts -> Mail -> Profiles

Comment: Going through that process brings up the exact same delete dialog i get going through the Windows Mail client. And with it the same issue as above